# Iterate over dict from value to value

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, iteration

I have a dictionary like this :

```
data = {1: [u'-', u's'], 2: [u'je', u'co', u'na'], ...}
```

The KEY is the LENGTH of the words that belong to it. I want to call a function (that will count levenshtein distance) for words that are longer than X and shorter than Y. How would I do it ?

The main problem is getting the dictionary length because len() returns the number of items in the dictionary, not keys.

Now I am doing it like this:

```
for k in data:
    if k >= len(word)-distance and k <= len(word)+distance:
    for item in data[k]:
        if levenshtein(word, item) == distance:
                    words.append(item)
return words
```

Comment: Which part precisely are you stuck on? Getting the keys between X and Y? Accessing the values for those keys? Calling the function on all items in those lists? Please be specific.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/0.12.0 and https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries will get you started. Post the code you have now and you'll get better answers.

Comment: I would like to get rid of the first if by changing the "for k in data" ..sorry for me not beeing clear

Comment: Please clarify your post: What is `data`? Is that the dict example? What are `X` and `Y`? Are they the keys of this dict? If you are asking how to get the keys of the dict in between certain values, you can do `[k for k in data if X<k<y]`

Comment: The indentation of your code is wrong. Also, in Python you can write the  statement as `if len(word)-distance <= k <= len(word)+distance:`. Note the length of the list associated with a given key `k` is just `len(data[k])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data.keys() will give you the keys, you can iterate over them.

Comment: Thank you I must have missed this when I was looking through the documentation....

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all words with length between X and Y with

```
sum((words for key, words in data.items() if X<key<Y), [])
```